# Install Symfony 4 in a subfolder of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, url-routing, symfony4

I hope that this question is not a duplicate, but I only found articles or questions about this for old versions of Symfony. I am new to Symfony 4 and I would like to create a new application with it and install it as a part of an already existing website (`domain` below). The Sf 4 app goes into the `admin/` subdirectory shown in the hierarchy below. `domain` uses the TYPO3 CMS, but I’m not sure that it matters for this question.

First, here is the directory structure :

```
/home/webuser/domain/
    public/ (this is the document root for "domain.localhost")
        admin/ (the Symfony app goes here)
            public/
            …
        …
        typo3/
        .htaccess
        index.php
        …
        composer.json
```

I am currently working on the website on my local machine and I would like to access the Symfony application root from `domain.localhost/admin`. I am using an Apache virtual host and the `domain/public` folder is the document root of `domain` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/home/webuser/www/domain/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding the following rewrite rule to my VirtualHost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/home/webuser/www/domain/public"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^/admin/(.*)$" "/admin/public/$1"
    LogLevel trace1
</VirtualHost>
```

But this seems to work only when I visit `http://domain.localhost/admin/` : I then see the "Welcome to Symfony 4.2.7" page. As soon as I try to visit a subpage, I get a 404 error. I tried to create my first page at `lucky/number` as explained in the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html), and looking at the Apache error log, I have lines such as :

```
[Mon Apr 29 18:52:09.472043 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22250:tid 140404453660416] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:43084] ::1 - - [domain.localhost/sid#55a33c704bf8][rid#7fb260002bd0/initial] [perdir /home/webuser/www/domain/public/] pass through /home/webuser/www/domain/public/admin/public/lucky

[Mon Apr 29 18:52:09.472087 2019] [core:info] [pid 22250:tid 140404453660416] [client ::1:43084] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/webuser/www/domain/public/admin/public/lucky/number
```

Now, TYPO3 has an `.htaccess` file containing URL rewrites, but I don’t think that they are interfering. Below, I just added myself the `admin/` folder in the rule after the comment that starts with "Stop rewrite processing", so that we are not redirected to the home page of the `domain` website when the file is not found :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
    # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
    RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

    # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

    # Access block for folders
    RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) - [F]
    RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

    # Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
    # the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

    # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
    # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
    RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico|admin/) - [L]

    # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
    # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

The production server will be a dedicated system, so I can modify anything I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to install the Apache pack, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48546361/1738984)