# Symfony5 throws 404 in browser, but route is found in cli

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, symfony5, symfony-routing

Iam using react+symfony with webpack. Everything works with simple url eg. one slash in url (*"/aboutus"*,*"/moodle"*) but when i try access route with multiple slashes(*"/admin/users"*) i get **NotFoundResource** Error. But with `router:match`i will find it.

Server log:

```sh
|WARN | SERVER GET  (404) /admin/users 
|ERROR| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /admin/users"" at /home/rtkpf/Programming/Niners/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136
```

router:match /admin/users

```sh
(master) [1]> bin/console router:match /admin/users


                                                                                                                        
 [OK] Route "index" matches                                                                                             
                                                                                                                        

+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | index                                                   |
| Path         | /{reactRouting}                                         |
| Path Regex   | {^/(?P<reactRouting>.+)?$}sDu                           |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | GET                                                     |
| Requirements | reactRouting: .+                                        |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\UserController::index()     |
|              | reactRouting: NULL                                      |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
|              | utf8: true                                              |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Component:

```php
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{reactRouting}", name="index", defaults={"reactRouting": null}, methods="GET", requirements={"reactRouting":".+"})
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Has someone experienced this before? Where can be a mistake?
P.S.: Ia m using symfony server

Comment: Do you see anything in the console of the Symfony server ? Is your request catched by the server or not at all ?

Comment: I had a similar problem which i solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48546361/4820276) way.

Comment: Although I am using Symfony:server, I tried adding .htacces. Everything same

Answer (score 1):

It says `App\Controller\UserController::index()` in router:match while your controller shows `DefaultController`, is this a possible problem?

There could also be a priority issue, since 5.1 you can use priorities in routing (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority), perhaps try adding `priority=-10,`  in the router annotation to prioritize it lower (0 is default) or `priority=10,`  in case you want to increase the priority somewhere else.

Comment: Since it uses a placeholder with no prefix, yes, the priority seems to be the issue, it will match any request. But it's the other way around, the priority of the `index` route should be _lower_.

Comment: You can also use a negative integer.

Comment: Yes, but that's a pretty important part of the answer, I commented to give you a chance to edit that in, as otherwise your suggestion won't do anything to solve the problem.

Comment: Very interesting. I don't know about route priorities. I dealt with UserController, error still here. Then I set DefaultController:index path to priority -10 as suggested. Error still persists